# modify notification before displaying on the notification bar Ionic 3?

Tags: angular, push-notification, ionic3, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugin-push

1. i am implementing push notification in IONIC 3 and using **phonegap-plugin-push**
2. now i want to modify data before displaying notification on notification bar
3. here is my code

   ```
   pushNotificationSetup() {
     const options: PushOptions = {
     android: {
       senderID: 'xxxxxxxxx',
       icon: 'icon',
       sound: true,
       vibrate: true
     },
     ios: {
       alert: true,
       badge: true,
       sound: true,
     }
     };
     const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);
     pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => {
       this.utilService.showToastMsg("success", notification.message);
     });

     pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((registration: any) => {
       this.storageService.setLocalStorage('registered-device', registration.registrationId);
     });

     pushObject.on('error').subscribe(error => console.error('Error with Push plugin', error));
   }
   ```

Comment: So what is the problem? can you specify what exactly is challenge for  you here? it feels like you have this method here: this.utilService.showToastMsg("success", notification.message); - which deals with 'presentation' of the message to user. This is where I guess you can modify the message. Unsure what is the problem here.